# Getting a list of available (languages) resx files

Tags: c#, list, localization, resx

Many many programs have communities that adds languages to the application after it got released.

So, in the settings window of a program, people can see a dropdown list of available languages. Well how do people code this while using resx files for localization? I've searched the web over and over again, but couldn't find any answer.

everything is working well, but now, i need to make a dropdown list of available languages. To make it clear, i do not want to release a new version every time someone created a new language for the program.. because that's what i have to do if i have to make a hardcoded list of languages that are available to pick.

How do i get a list of available resx files?

Comment: Why you use .resx files for localization instead of compiled satellite assemblies?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatic way to get all the available languages (in satellite assemblies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553244/programmatic-way-to-get-all-the-available-languages-in-satellite-assemblies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, even if you *could* get a list (and you can I guess, by inspecting the filesystem), depending on how you implemented your localisation, it may not be accurate (may have not provided a translation for the specific .resx you're looking for).

I'd suggest the best way to do this is in a .config somewhere (or database). That way you can disable languages independantly of the .resx system; which is something that will inevitably come up.

Comment: Is there a alternative for resX then, i absolutly want to give the user their own options to pick a language.

Comment: And you can; just list all the ones you support in a .config and display that :) resx method is the best way to do internationalisation.

Comment: I understand it ;) i forgot to comment that i also want the community give the opportunity to add new languages without having to edit a configuration file.

Comment: Well then you can just put it in a database record, and when the community adds a language pack you set that field appropriately.

Answer (score 5):

You can programatically list the cultures available in your application. The approach is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11047894/1346070)