# Get all available cultures from a .resx file group

Tags: .net, resources, internationalization, resx, localization

I need to programatically list the available cultures in a resx file group, but the ResourceManager class doesn't seem to help.

I may have :

```
Labels.resx
Labels.fr-FR.resx
Labels.ro-RO.resx
```

and so on

However, how can I find these three (or how many would there be) cultures at runtime?

Comment: I don't think you really need .net in the title and have a tag for .net.

Comment: Also just looking through SO this seems like a duplicate to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283602/getting-a-list-of-available-languages-resx-files

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate but this has a better answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look for satellite assemblies in your application's directory: for each subdirectory, check if its name corresponds to a culture name, and if it contains a `.resources.dll` file :

```
public IEnumerable<CultureInfo> GetAvailableCultures()
{
    var programLocation = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
    var resourceFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(programLocation) + ".resources.dll";
    var rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(programLocation));
    return from c in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
           join d in rootDir.EnumerateDirectories() on c.IetfLanguageTag equals d.Name
           where d.EnumerateFiles(resourceFileName).Any()
           select c;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me with Resources.resx and Resources.el.resx files under Properties in a WPF project. See below an alternative that did work

Answer (score 6):

based on the answer by @hans-holzbart at [Programmatic way to get all the available languages (in satellite assemblies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553244/programmatic-way-to-get-all-the-available-languages-in-satellite-assemblies) but fixed to not return the InvariantCulture too and wrapped into a reusable method:

```
public static IEnumerable<CultureInfo> GetAvailableCultures()
{
  List<CultureInfo> result = new List<CultureInfo>();

  ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(typeof(Resources));

  CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
  foreach (CultureInfo culture in cultures)
  {
    try
    {
      if (culture.Equals(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) continue; //do not use "==", won't work

      ResourceSet rs = rm.GetResourceSet(culture, true, false);
      if (rs != null)
        result.Add(culture);
    }
    catch (CultureNotFoundException)
    {
      //NOP
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

using that method, you can get a list of strings to add to some ComboBox with the following:

```
public static ObservableCollection<string> GetAvailableLanguages()
{
  var languages = new ObservableCollection<string>();
  var cultures = GetAvailableCultures();
  foreach (CultureInfo culture in cultures)
    languages.Add(culture.NativeName + " (" + culture.EnglishName + " [" + culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName + "])");
  return languages;
}
```