# WPF Localize Extension : Translate window at run-time

Tags: c#, wpf, internationalization

I'm in the process of translating a WPF window. I'm using [WPF Localize Extension](http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/) . So far I only have a Spanish translation for testing purposes in `<Resource>.es.resx` file . At design time translations work . So I guess I'm on the right track .

I have included menu items to translate the GUI dynamically at run time . Initially I tried this (naïve) command ...

```
public class CmdTranslateUI : ICommand
{
    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        // TODO: Query available translations
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        LocalizeDictionary.Instance.Culture = new CultureInfo(
            (string) parameter);
    }
}
```

... and menu items for each language are bound to it in XAML this way .

```
<MenuItem Header="Español" CommandParameter="es-ES">
    <MenuItem.Command>
        <l:CmdTranslateUI />
    </MenuItem.Command>
</MenuItem>
```

The fact is that such approach is not working . Culture info remains set to `"en-US"` anyway . I read that on setting `LocalizeDictionary.Instance.Culture` its `DictionaryEvent` is triggered, so I thought this would update the GUI automatically . Obviously I'm wrong .

On the other hand , it seems current thread's culture won't influence library behavior either.

So I ask ...

Q:

- What's the recommended approach to translate a window at run time with [WPF Localize Extension](http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/) ?
- How could I list available translations ?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems I introduced a typo by accident last time I compiled the library (or I had ghosts in my HDD / CPU) . Language switching is working now after setting `LocalizeDictionary.Instance.SetCurrentThreadCulture` .

Just for the record , this is what command class mentioned above should look like

```
public class CmdTranslateUI : ICommand
{
    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo((string)parameter);

        foreach (CultureInfo c in ResxLocalizationProvider.Instance.AvailableCultures)
        {
            if (ci.Name == c.Name)
                return true;
            else if (ci.Parent.Name == c.Name)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        LocalizeDictionary.Instance.SetCurrentThreadCulture = true;
        LocalizeDictionary.Instance.Culture = new CultureInfo(
            (string) parameter);
    }
}
```

... at least that's a simple approach that will work as long as resource files l10n provider is active.

Comment: have you seen the LocalizeDictionary.Instance.MergedAvailableCultures property btw?

Comment: Not really , but if you have an alternative solution I'd encourage you to share it .

--
Regards

Comment: from that method's name, sounds like it gives you the available cultures (of the current provider I guess) ready to add them to a listbox

Comment: just tried the MergedAvailableCultures, but seems it does something different. Before calling LocalizeDictionary.Instance.Culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture it just returns 1 culture, the invariant one, but after calling it returns 2 cultures, the invariant one and the current culture of the thread (the one the app was launched with from the OS). Not sure where that method is useful

Comment: I ended up using the solution I posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226974/get-all-available-cultures-from-a-resx-file-group to get the available cultures

Answer (score 1):

The `LocalizeExtension`'s `Culture` property is independent of the threads UI culture. Sometimes this may be desired, because the threads culture does affect a lot of things. We are using the extension in our own project and settings the threads culture manually to match the `LocalizeDictionary`'s culture.

Normally this should update the UI automatically. Make sure you are using the `LocText` markup extension in your XAML, e.g:

```
<TextBlock Text="{lex:LocText Bla:Bla:Bla}" />
```

**Update:
To get the list of available translations you might try this:**

[Get all available cultures from a .resx file group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226974/get-all-available-cultures-from-a-resx-file-group)

However I would recommend that you just provide a fix list of languages in code or if you are using an IoC container, register the available languages there.

Comment: Yes I'm using [the add-in](http://wpflocalizeaddin.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screenshots%20Demo&referringTitle=Home) so `lex:LocText` is spread all over XAML document . This happens out-of-the-box

Comment: see my reply on how to get available cultures at the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226974/get-all-available-cultures-from-a-resx-file-group that you posted. Couldn't make the answer that was there to work with WPF

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer OP's question, but thought I'd post it here anyway for those wandering here from Google since the title of the question is relevant.

I was having a problem where my application would be partially translated when changing the language in runtime. At first thought it was a convention problem since I had separate resources for each page, but the real problem was that the last control in the first page failed to translate, so it broke the chain and as a result all the subpages didn't get translated.

I was translating the `FallbackValue` of a textblock, I was using this property to show a default text when the binding was null.

Anyway, to catch errors like this, you can subscribe to the following event:

```
LocalizeDictionary.Instance.MissingKeyEvent += (sender, args) =>
{
    //Do something
};
```