# Get available languages from resource

Tags: c#, .net, resources

I should programmatic get all languages, for which there are resources. Can someone point me to the way, how I can do this?

**Update**

Now I have adding code for enumerating all resource-files, parsing the filenames and getting the languages out of the filenames. But I think, there should be a bether solution for this.

Comment: It's a WPF-Desktop-Application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatic way to get all the available languages (in satellite assemblies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553244/programmatic-way-to-get-all-the-available-languages-in-satellite-assemblies)