# MVC 4 Resource files and language dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, resources

I've implemented multi language support following this blog post http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2010/05/06/localization-in-asp.net-mvc-ndash-3-days-investigation-1-day.aspx

Only some of the pages are in different languages, so I'm trying to create a html helper to show a dropdown to select the language they want. I want to make this html helper bit intelligent and implement it so that it will show the different languages if it's available when I provide it with a resource type.

Say, I have sample.resx, sample.ko.resx, sample.zh.resx and say their namespace is Resources.Contacts . Is it possible to find out different language resource files of a given type, namespace or whatever at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

possible duplicate because it has been answered here already:

[Programmatic way to get all the available languages (in satellite assemblies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553244/programmatic-way-to-get-all-the-available-languages-in-satellite-assemblies)

There are certain workarounds to figure out if the languages are available. You'll either have to check if the resource supports the culture, or, if check the folders within your bin directory (for each language, there might be a folder with the name of the culture).

Comment: I came across that post and tried it, the answer in it doesn't work for me as MVC resources are compiled to a dll. I tried the answer there by Hans Holzbart but that didn't work either. I passed my resource type and I have ko, zh resource files. but it didn't find them.